# image processing - exposure effect on image

Tags: java, android, image, temperature, colormatrix

I am currently working on an image processing android app. I am desperately looking for an exposure color matrix that I can use in order to change the exposure of an image. However, I could not find any usable code for that ;/

Is there anyone you could help me out please. I'd really appreciate it !

Comment: Don't you want to change the "brightness" (i.e. black to white), rather than the color compoents?

Comment: No I want the exposure color matrix, i already have a working brightness one :)

Comment: It will be great to have it as a plugin to https://github.com/oliver-moran/jimp library.

Answer (score 1):

Brightness: (Adjust all pixels by adding or subtracting a set amount)

```
[
   1, 0, 0, 0, v, //R
   0, 1, 0, 0, v, //G
   0, 0, 1, 0, v, //B
   0, 0, 0, 1, 0, //A
]
```

Exposure: (Adjust all pixels by using a consistent multiplier)

```
[
   v, 0, 0, 0, 0, //R
   0, v, 0, 0, 0, //G
   0, 0, v, 0, 0, //B
   0, 0, 0, 1, 0, //A
]
```

Comment: I think The second matrix is for contrast not for exposure